# NLP integration with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nlp

Anyone done integration of NLP with mongodb database?
Currently multiple APIs available to identify entities from natural language .
Basic requirement is to generate query .

Regards,
Jalpesh

Comment: you need to have a specific question, please see the guidelines for asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. The answer to your question `Anyone done integration of NLP with mongodb database?` is either `yes` or `no`, hardly what you are actually after.

Answer (score 1):

My own .NET library AboditNLP can do this. (Excuse the plug but there are no others that can do this as far as I know)

It converts an English query into an expression tree and can then rewrite that expression tree into a SQL, LINQ-to-objects or MongoDB query.

e.g.

[image: Image showing an NLP query being converted into MongoDB]

Comment: We have same requirement.
User asks questions in English then  it should convert in mongoDB query which will return answers.

can you explain in detail ?

Comment: @JalpeshShelar Not here, this site is Q&A only, but if you contact me directly I can tell you more.